# How to create and refer custom rules of code analysis in visual studio 2012?

Tags: code-analysis

I need to create my ouwn custom rules of code analyzer and add them to ruleset file. For this i have created a sample custom rules project in vs2012 but i am not able to add my rules to the ruleset of vs2012.

Could you please help by providing the solution.

Thanks 
Murali

Answer (score 1):

I found these descriptions for VS2015:

- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/MetaCompilation.Analyzers/Core/ReadMe.md#instructions
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx

I have to try if they're applying for VS2012/2013, too.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could find is a blog entry on MSDN describing it for VS 2010, hope it helps

[How to write custom static code analysis rules and integrate them into Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately the instructions for Visual Studio 2010 do not seem to apply to Visual Studio 2015 and 2017. I've created a custom rule and I can't fathom how to get VS to execute it in a Code Analysis run.